# Simplifying UNION query to use a single SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

**The data:**

I have an sqlite table with the following example rows:

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
| id          | groupId        | selected        |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|           1 | -1             | 0               |
|           2 | 2              | 0               |
|           3 | 2              | 1               |
|           4 | 5              | 0               |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

It's pretty simple, if the `groupId` is less than 0, than it's a single element, else it's in a group (even if the `groupId` is not referencing any of the `id`s.

**The query:**

I want to filter every element whose `groupId` is less than 0 and it is not `selected` plus every first element from each group. From this table, `id`s: 1, 2 and 4.

**The current solution with `UNION`:**

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE (groupId < 0 AND selected = 0 ) UNION SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE groupId >= 0 GROUP BY groupId)`

**The goal:**

I want to change the query to use just a single `SELECT` statement. That single statement can use anything, but aggregate functions.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: If using `SELECT *` what do you want your `GROUP BY` to do?

Comment: That `GROUP BY` is meant to filter every first item for every group. Maybe i tested wrong, but it seemed to be work on sqlite.
BTW, if the current solution is bad, please use the english description for it in the **the query** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a union, it can all be done in a single WHERE clause. Here is the query that will return the list of IDs that you requested.

```
SELECT  MIN_ID
FROM    (
        SELECT  GROUPID
                ,MIN(ID) AS MIN_ID
        FROM    ELEMENTS
        WHERE   (GROUPID < 0 AND SELECTED = 0)
        OR      GROUPID >= 0
        GROUP BY
                GROUPID
        )
```

Here is a second query based on the comments below.

```
SELECT  GROUPID
        ,MIN(ID) AS MIN_ID
FROM    ELEMENTS
WHERE   (GROUPID < 0 AND SELECTED = 0)
OR      GROUPID >= 0        
GROUP BY
        GROUPID
```

Comment: Thanks! I need every column of Element table in the resultset. Is it possible to modify your query to achieve this? Also i forgot that i cannot use agreggate functions (all of these a limit of the used query builder). :(

Comment: Do you just need the first ID, as stated in your question, or all IDs for the groups that match the criteria?

Comment: I need the first element of each group. Is this clear? Sorry, but English is not my first language.

Comment: Sorry adding so much additional details in comments, i really need to write better OPs. It is just reduced example, in real there are lots of other columns, so i really use `SELECT *`. Another thing that i forgot to mention in the OP, but commented in a previous comment, that i cannot use aggregate functions (like `MIN()` what you are using in your queries).

Comment: I'm not sure I want to ask, but why can you not use aggregate functions? Also `SELECT *` is a really, really bad practice.

Comment: The question is just! I'm using an ORM library (ORMLite actually), so when i mapping the rows to Java objects, i have to read all of the columns. The limitations also come because of the lib.

Comment: I am not familiar with ORMLite, but would it be possible to create a VIEW from the query (includeing the MIN aggregate function) and then map from that VIEW to the Java objects?

Comment: I managed to build a query which works with ORMLite. I managed to use an aggregate function. :) The query is actually not simplified at all, but at least works: `SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE (Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Elements WHERE (GroupId < 0 AND Selected = 0 ) ) OR Id IN (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Elements WHERE GroupId >= 0 GROUP BY GroupId ) ) ORDER BY Title`.